# calculus topic classification

Tags: calculus

Okay, so in high school, for us, they don't have Calculus I, II, III, but rather, they offer AP Calculus AB and AP Calculus BC.

I was wondering where trig substitutions, hyperbolic functions, and inverse trig function integration fall (AB or BC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AP Calculus AB and BC are not a sequence of courses.  Each are usually taught over a year of high school.  But BC does a lot more.

- Integration by trigonometric substitution is in BC but not in AB
- inverse trig functions are in AB (and BC)
- hyperbolic functions are usually not covered in either.

At my university we say that the topics in AP Calculus AB cover our Calculus I course, and those in BC cover both Calculus I and II.